# Pthreads - Writing a reusable barrier using mutexes and busy waiting

Tags: pthreads

The following is a homework question that I'm struggling with because I was sick and missed a lecture.

---

*The code in the loop body is an attempt at implementing a reusable barrier using mutexes and busy waiting. However, this code can deadlock. Fix it so that the barrier works correctly in each iteration of the for loop.*

```
Line  1:    // count1 and count2 are volatile and initialized to zero
Line  2:    for (…) { // many iterations
Line  3:        pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
Line  4:        count1++;
Line  5:        count2 = 0;
Line  6:        pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
Line  7:        while (count1 < threads);
Line  8:    
Line  9:        // do some computation here
Line 10:    
Line 11:        pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
Line 12:        count2++;
Line 13:        count1 = 0;
Line 14:        pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
Line 15:        while (count2 < threads);
Line 16:    }
```

---

I'd like to learn this material on my own, tho I seem to find solutions that use material we haven't learned in class (e.g. not using busy waiting and mutexes.)

**Understanding the problem**

I think I understand the problem: When the last thread increments on line #4, all other threads are released from the busy waiting on line #7.  This could cause problems if line #12 is reached before the last thread passes the busy wait on line #7, right?

**Solving the problem**

I was considering maybe decrementing count1 on line 8, and checking that it has reached zero by line 10, but then I'd run into data race issues.  So maybe something like this:

```
for (…) { // many iterations
   pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
   count1++;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
   while (count1 < threads);

   // do some computation here

   pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
   count2++;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
   while (count2 < threads);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
   count1--;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
   while (count1 != 0);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
   count2--;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
   while (count2 != 0);
}
```

Any help or reference material would be greatly appreciated (my textbook doesn't cover this.)

Comment: For anyone who was curious, my answer was correct (although inefficient.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace both barriers (at the start and end of the loop) with this:

```
while (count2 != 0)
    ;

pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
count1++;
if (count1 < threads)
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);

    while (count2 == 0)
        ;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier_mutex);
}
else
{
    count2 = 1;
}
count1--;
if (count1 == 0)
    count2 = 0;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier_mutex);
```

`count1` is now the count of threads waiting at the barrier, and `count2` is a flag to indicate whether the barrier is currently waitable ("up", indicated by `0`) or still releasing threads from the last wait ("down", indicated by `1`).

A thread wanting to enter the barrier first spins until the barrier is up - this avoids the race you've identified, when threads try to enter the barrier while it still hasn't finished releasing threads from the last wait.  It then adds itself to the waiting threads, and if it's not the last thread in, spins until the barrier is down.  The last thread into the barrier instead takes the barrier down.  Once the barrier is down, each thread removes itself from the list of waiters, and the last thread out of the barrier puts the barrier back up.

The key idea here which I imagine was in the lecture material is to identify the last thread to wait on the barrier as special and assign it additional housekeeping work.  You can also see that your idea of decrementing the waiting count was on the right track.

Note that I can't be certain that this is the answer your lecturer was after - they almost certainly had some specific teaching point to this, and you should probably try and find out if a recording of the lecture you missed is available, see if a classmate has lecture notes you can borrow, or just consult the lecturer or tutor directly.